# Trouble with Embedding Fonts

Tags: css, fonts

I am working on a page locally and trying to get a particular font but I'm having some trouble and was hoping someone might be able to look at my code and see if there's anything wrong,

Here is my code:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'nunito_sansbold';
    src: url('nunitosans-bold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('nunitosans-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'nunito_sansregular';
    src: url('nunitosans-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('nunitosans-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
body {
    font-family: 'nunito_sansregular', Arial, 'sans-serif';
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 1365px;
    }
```

`

Comment: Your code does not say much, if there is an error accessing the font you should indicate what the console or the browser's network tab says.